# How can I tell whether an attack is blockable?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

It is not fun having to resort to trial-and-error to find out whether an attack can be blocked with Wonder Guts or not. Is there any way to tell through observation? Is there some sort of pattern?

Comment: Lasers are blockable with the Unite Sword, not Guts. That's all I know, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more experience with the game, these does indeed seem to be a pattern.

**Blunt attacks are blockable by Guts.** Punches, kicks, stomps, smacks, rams, headbutts, ground pounds, and so on can be blocked with Guts. The main exception is when the enemy is in an "enraged" state; there are one or two other minor exceptions.

**Some blunt attacks require a Guts of sufficient size to block.** One attack that operates by this rule is when the boss of 002-C tries to squish you with its fist. If your Guts is of size 1 or 2 (composed of 10-19 or 20-49 morphers), the punch will be held at bay, but once the shield goes down it'll hit you anyway. On the other hand, the attack can be successfully blocked and halted by a Guts of size 3 or higher (50 or more morhpers).

**Nothing else is blockable by Guts.** Holding out Unite Hand will make you immune to fire, Unite Sword makes you immune to lasers and electricity, and Unify Naginata will reflect projectile drills, but spikes, drills, blades, claws, and explosions can't be blocked by anything. They have to be avoided or dodged with Spring instead. Note however that swords small enough to be wielded by one person can be blocked.

Comment: Does that mean that one could use Guts to block Vorkken's sword when he attacks solo while the Guyzoch takes the form of a larger enemy?

Comment: Haven't been able to try it on him yet, but it works on other lone swordsmen.

Comment: @WillR. Yes I have confirmed that you can block solo Vorkken.